# Connecting to APNS for iPhone Using Python

Tags: iphone, python, ssl, push-notification

I'm trying to send push notifications to an iPhone using Python. I've exported my **certificate and private key** into a p12 file from keychain access and then converted it into pem file using the following command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cred.p12 -out cert.pem -nodes -clcerts
```

I'm using [APNSWrapper](http://code.google.com/p/apns-python-wrapper/wiki/APNSWrapperOverview) in Python for the connection.

I run the following code:

```
deviceToken = 'Qun\xaa\xd ... c0\x9c\xf6\xca' 

# create wrapper
wrapper = APNSNotificationWrapper('/path/to/cert/cert.pem', True)

# create message
message = APNSNotification()
message.token(deviceToken)
message.badge(5)

# add message to tuple and send it to APNS server
wrapper.append(message)
wrapper.notify()
```

And then I get the error message:

```
ssl.SSLError: (1, '_ssl.c:485: 
error:14094416:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate unknown')
```

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: So what was the problem? Certificate or service?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recently did this using Django - http://leecutsco.de/2009/07/14/push-on-the-iphone/

May be useful? It's making use of no extra libraries other than those included with Python already. Wouldn't take much to extract the send_message() method out.

Comment: I suggest to put the content to the answer instead of the link. Eventually the link may get outdated, in which case others may not be benefited from the answer.

Comment: Just as @Walty predicted, the link got broken. The new link is http://leecutsco.de/2009/07/14/push-on-the-iphone/ - it would be nice if the content was in answer.

Comment: I would appreciate if you recreated the URL, it directs me to not found page.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered the [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) package?  The below code is taken from [here](http://blog.nuclearbunny.org/2009/05/11/connecting-to-apple-push-notification-services-using-python-twisted/):

```
from struct import pack
from OpenSSL import SSL
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import ClientFactory, Protocol
from twisted.internet.ssl import ClientContextFactory

APNS_SERVER_HOSTNAME = "<insert the push hostname from your iPhone developer portal>"
APNS_SERVER_PORT = 2195
APNS_SSL_CERTIFICATE_FILE = "<your ssl certificate.pem>"
APNS_SSL_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE = "<your ssl private key.pem>"

class APNSClientContextFactory(ClientContextFactory):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv3_METHOD)
        self.ctx.use_certificate_file(APNS_SSL_CERTIFICATE_FILE)
        self.ctx.use_privatekey_file(APNS_SSL_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE)

    def getContext(self):
        return self.ctx

class APNSProtocol(Protocol):
    def sendMessage(self, deviceToken, payload):
        # notification messages are binary messages in network order
        # using the following format:
        # <1 byte command> <2 bytes length><token> <2 bytes length><payload>
        fmt = "!cH32cH%dc" % len(payload)
        command = 0
        msg = struct.pack(fmt, command, deviceToken,
                          len(payload), payload)
        self.transport.write(msg)

class APNSClientFactory(ClientFactory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        print "Connected to APNS Server %s:%u" % (addr.host, addr.port)
        return APNSProtocol()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print "Lost connection. Reason: %s" % reason

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection failed. Reason: %s" % reason

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reactor.connectSSL(APNS_SERVER_HOSTNAME, 
                       APNS_SERVER_PORT,
                       APNSClientFactory(), 
                       APNSClientContextFactory())
    reactor.run()
```

Comment: @coonj Have you tried this with any success? Do you have any examples of using the code to send messages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

there were a few bugs in the originally posted code, so here's a corrected version that works for me.

```
from struct import pack
from OpenSSL import SSL
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import ClientFactory, Protocol
from twisted.internet.ssl import ClientContextFactory
import binascii
import struct

APNS_SERVER_HOSTNAME = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com"
APNS_SERVER_PORT = 2195
APNS_SSL_CERTIFICATE_FILE = "<your ssl certificate.pem>"
APNS_SSL_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE = "<your ssl private key.pem>"
DEVICE_TOKEN = "<hexlified device token>"
MESSAGE = '{"aps":{"alert":"twisted test"}}'

class APNSClientContextFactory(ClientContextFactory):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv3_METHOD)
        self.ctx.use_certificate_file(APNS_SSL_CERTIFICATE_FILE)
        self.ctx.use_privatekey_file(APNS_SSL_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE)

    def getContext(self):
        return self.ctx

class APNSProtocol(Protocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
        print "connection made"
        self.sendMessage(binascii.unhexlify(DEVICE_TOKEN), MESSAGE)
        self.transport.loseConnection()

    def sendMessage(self, deviceToken, payload):
        # notification messages are binary messages in network order
        # using the following format:
        # <1 byte command> <2 bytes length><token> <2 bytes length><payload>
        fmt = "!cH32sH%ds" % len(payload)
        command = '\x00'
        msg = struct.pack(fmt, command, 32, deviceToken,
                          len(payload), payload)
        print "%s: %s" %(binascii.hexlify(deviceToken), binascii.hexlify(msg))
        self.transport.write(msg)

class APNSClientFactory(ClientFactory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        print "Connected to APNS Server %s:%u" % (addr.host, addr.port)
        return APNSProtocol()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print "Lost connection. Reason: %s" % reason

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection failed. Reason: %s" % reason

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reactor.connectSSL(APNS_SERVER_HOSTNAME,
                       APNS_SERVER_PORT,
                       APNSClientFactory(),
                       APNSClientContextFactory())
    reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to update to latest APNSWrapper version (0.4). There is build-in support of openssl command line tool (openssl s_client) now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried both `APNSWrapper` and Lee Peckham's code and couldn't get it to work under Snow Leopard with Python 2.6. After a lot of trial and error it finally worked with `pyOpenSSL`.

I already did a post with details and code snippets [here](http://ramin.firoozye.com/2009/09/09/push-notification-and-python-django/) so I'll just refer you there.